# mysqli Inserting form data into two tables

Tags: php, mysql, insert, prepared-statement

User enters player information into form (1-12 players at a time)

$player query: checks for duplicate player and either enters a new player or updates a player already in the players table.

$pid query:  gets the matching player's ID ($playerID)

$roster query:  inserts roster information to the rosters table - schoolID, playerID, uniform, and if he's on the varsity level or not

The $player query works great!
The $pid query...does a good job getting the $playerID (I echo it out)

Where my problem comes is I can't seem to get the $roster query to recognize $playerID.

```
$schoolID = $_POST['school']; 
$varsity = $_POST['varsity']; 
$season = $_POST['season'];

        $player = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO a_players(schoolID,nameFirst,nameLast,feet,inches,grade,position,varsity) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        feet = ?,
        inches = ?,
        varsity = ?
        ");
        $player->bind_param('sssssssssss',$schoolID,$fname,$lname,$feet,$inches,$grade,$position,$varsity,$feet,$inches,$varsity);
    
    
        $pid = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM a_players WHERE nameFirst = ? AND nameLast = ? AND schoolID = ?");
        $pid->bind_param('sss',$fname,$lname,$schoolID);
        
            
        $roster = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO a_rosters(schoolID, playerID, uniform, varsity, season) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $roster->bind_param('sssss', $schoolID, $playerID, $uniform, $varsity, $season);
    

    
        foreach ($_POST['uniform'] as $k => $uniform)  {
            $fname = $_POST['nameFirst'][$k];
            $lname = $_POST['nameLast'][$k];
            $feet = $_POST['feet'][$k];
            $inches = $_POST['inches'][$k];
            $grade = $_POST['grade'][$k];
            $position = $_POST['position'][$k];
            
            $name = "$fname $lname";
            $slug = strtolower("$fname-$lname");
            
          
            $taxonomy = "post_tag";
            
            
            $player->execute();
                
                echo '<div>' .$fname,$lname,$schoolID .'</div>';

                $pid->execute();
                $pid->bind_result($playerID);
                $pid->fetch();

                
                echo '<div>playerID: ' . $playerID .' value of row: '. $row .'</div>';

            
            $roster->execute();
```

The echos around $pid->execute are just there to see what's being passed.  Once it's working, those get removed.